# Concat results of multiple AJAX calls into single variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-online, rest

I would like to call 2 recursive API calls to generate a JQuery datatables page date range 2016-2021. The year filter on these API calls below split the API response to overcome the 5000 item list limit threshold established by Sharepoint Online.

I am unable to concat all results into my var allResults. With the code below, i only get the results generated for 2021. However, I can see that 12 successful API calls are made via Chrome XHR for years 2016-2021 but the results are not being concat into the var. Kindly advise.

```
var results;
var allResults = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    load();
});

function load() {
    for (let year = 2016; year < 2022; year++) {
        var yearh1 = $.ajax({    
            url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=5000&$select=*&$filter=(Col_Date%20ge%20datetime'"+(year-1)+"-12-31T20:00:00.000Z')%20and%20(Col_Date%20lt%20datetime'"+year+"-06-01T00:00:00.000Z')",    
            type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},    
            success: mySuccHandler, error: myErrHandler}); 

        var yearh2 = $.ajax({    
            url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=5000&$select=*&$filter=(Col_Date%20ge%20datetime'"+year+"-06-01T00:00:00.000Z')%20and%20(Col_Date%20le%20datetime'"+year+"-12-31T00:00:00.000Z')",    
            type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},    
            success: mySuccHandler, error: myErrHandler}); 
    }

    function mySuccHandler(a) {
        results = a.d.results;
        if (allResults.length > 0)
            allResults = allResults.concat(results);
        else
            allResults = results;        
    }
    function myErrHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not complete call: " + errorMessage);        
    };

   $.when(yearh1, yearh2).done(function(a1, a2){
      // console.log(allResults);
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
        data:allResults,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        columns: [
                    { data: "Title" },
                    { data: "Reg_x0020_No" },
        ]
    });
   });  
};
```

#### Addendum

After reading some answers I added a `var allRequests`. This now allows me to store results from all API calls, but does not concat results and pass it to datatables for table rendering.

```
var results;
var allResults = [];
var allRequests = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    load();
});

function load() {
for (let year = 2016; year < 2022; year++) {
    var yearh1 = $.ajax({    
        url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=5000&$select=*&$filter=(Incident_x0020_Date%20ge%20datetime%27"+(year-1)+"-12-31T20:00:00.000Z%27)%20and%20(Incident_x0020_Date%20lt%20datetime%27"+year+"-06-01T00:00:00.000Z%27)",    
        type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},    
        success: mySuccHandler, error: myErrHandler}); 
    var yearh2 = $.ajax({    
        url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=5000&$select=*&$filter=(Incident_x0020_Date%20ge%20datetime%27"+year+"-06-01T00:00:00.000Z%27)%20and%20(Incident_x0020_Date%20le%20datetime%27"+year+"-12-31T00:00:00.000Z%27)",    
        type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},    
        success: mySuccHandler, error: myErrHandler}); 

       allRequests.push(yearh1);
       allRequests.push(yearh2); 
}       
    function mySuccHandler(a) {
        results = a.d.results;
        if (allResults.length > 0)
            allResults = allResults.concat(results);
        else
            allResults = results;
    }

    function myErrHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not complete call: " + errorMessage);        
    };

   $.when($, allRequests).done(function(a1, a2){
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
        data:allResults,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        columns:[
                    { data: "Title" },
                    { data: "Reg_x0020_No" }
                ]
    });
   });  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop overwrites the values of `yearh1` and `yearh2` in each iteration, so that is why the `$.when()` call will only deal with the results from the last two requests.

You could collect the responses into an array instead of assignment to `yearh1` and `yearh2`, and then spread that array to `$.when()`.

Also, I would suggest not using the `success` handler, but deal with the data only when you perform the `$.when()` call.

Here is how that could look:

```
function load() {
    const promises = [];
    for (let year = 2016; year < 2022; year++) {
        promises.push($.ajax({
            url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=5000&$select=*&$filter=(Col_Date%20ge%20datetime'"+(year-1)+"-12-31T20:00:00.000Z')%20and%20(Col_Date%20lt%20datetime'"+year+"-06-01T00:00:00.000Z')",
            type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
        }), $.ajax({    
            url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=5000&$select=*&$filter=(Col_Date%20ge%20datetime'"+year+"-06-01T00:00:00.000Z')%20and%20(Col_Date%20le%20datetime'"+year+"-12-31T00:00:00.000Z')",   
            type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
        })); 
    }

    function myErrHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not complete call: " + errorMessage);        
    }

    $.when(...promises).then(function(...responses){
        const allResults = responses.map(x => x[0].d.results);
        console.log(allResults);
        $('#table_id').DataTable({
            data:allResults,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            columns: [
                { data: "Title" },
                { data: "Reg_x0020_No" },
            ]
        });
    }).catch(myErrHandler);  
}
```

Finally, consider using the native Web API for dealing with HTTP requests and Promises: `fetch` instead of `$.ajax`, `Promise.all` instead of `$.when`. The interface is slightly different, but it is worth to make the transition to these standards.

Comment: Greetings trincot, Appreciate the input. I tried the your code above with nil luck. I'm new to this level of coding. The API calls are not made and nill data is returned through chrome XHR. Kindly have a look at my revised code in the original post and suggest.

Comment: Why do you pass `$` as argument to `$.when`? `$.when` expects one or more arguments that are Deferreds (or promises). You pass it `$` and an array, neither of which are what is expected. (And please don't update the question resolving issues that I addressed in my answer -- it makes my answer look stupid). If you say the API calls are not made, then that means `load` is not called. If load is called, then it is absolutely guaranteed that the API calls (requests) are made. How did you verify that they are (not) made?

Comment: On a second note, the code that you have integrated into your question comes from another answer that has been deleted -- it is not my code. But again, you should never integrate answer-code into your question. This is making answers irrelevant and future visitors will not have a clue why the answer has the same code as the question. It makes these answers look stupid.

Comment: I updated your question to include the original text for the reasons mentioned above.